# Cuadros de color negro al visualizar documentos con PDF View en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, pdf

Acabo de implementar pdf view para visualizar desde un boton distintos documentos, funciona todo ok pero los archivos pdf en algunas partes se ven cuadros de color negro. Este es el código que tengo implementado. Pienso que quizas es un problema con la versión del pdf view que estoy usando. Cuando es un pdf creado desde un scaner lee sin problemas. Por lo visto el problema se da solo cuando son pdf creados desde un documento word.

```
if(intent != null)
{
    val viewType = intent.getStringExtra("ViewType")

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(viewType) || viewType != null)
    {
        if (viewType.equals("assets"))
        {

            pdf_view.fromAsset("2 Listado Trabajadores.pdf")
                .password(null)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .onDraw{ canvas, pageWidth, pageHeight, displayedPage ->
                }.onDrawAll { canvas, pageWidth, pageHeight, displayedPage ->
                }
                .onPageChange{page, pageCount ->

                }.onPageError{page, t->
                    Toast.makeText (this@MainActivity6, "Error while opening page "+page, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("ERROR",""+t.localizedMessage);



                }
                .onTap { false }
                .onRender{ nbPages, pageWidth, pageHeight ->
                    pdf_view.fitToWidth()
                }
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .invalidPageColor(Color.RED)
                .load()


        }

    }
}
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estás usando [esta librería](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) la cual se ve que ya no es mantenida. Podrías buscar otra o usar la clase [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) que viene en android. Pero para una mejor experiencia te recomiendo dejar que el usuario abra el pdf con otra applicación.

Como el pdf está en el directorio de tu app necesitas crear un [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing) para que otras apps puedan acceder a él. Para eso debes declararlo en el manifest

```
<application ...>
    ...
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

luego creas un archivo en la carpeta `res/xml/` para definir que archivos quieres compartir. En este ejemplo son todos los que están en el cache:

```
// res/xml/file_paths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="documents" path="/" />
</paths>
```

finalmente creas un intent con la uri generada por tu FileProvider

```
private val authority = "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider"

private fun openPDF(fileName: String) {
    val file = cache(fileName)
    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, file)
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File"))
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        // do something
    }
}

private fun cache(fileName: String) = File(cacheDir, fileName).apply {
    // read from assets
    assets.open(fileName).use { input ->
        // copy to cache
        outputStream().use { input.copyTo(it) }
    }
}
```